# How can I change the maven SNAPSHOT unique version format?

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

When I maven deploy a snapshot build such as `myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT` maven will helpfully tag the snapshot with the date and the build number - something like `myproject-1.0-20160720.182254-6.jar`. Is there any way I can control the format of this unique tag?

In particular I'm trying to solve two problems:

- I want to know the exact artifact that I just uploaded so that I can pull it into a docker image. There are potentially several builds in parallel for different developers so I need to get the exact version.
- I want to tie the snapshot unique ID to the checkin id in git.

Answer (score -1):

Use a concrete version number in the pom, this way you will have predictable builds that you can reuse later on.
And use e.g.:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:set -DnewVersion=1.1 -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

to set the version and do a `mvn clean deploy` afterwards, this way you will know what version you can use in docker.

Comment: I tried that - but then maven thought it was a release and sent it to the release repository not the snapshot repository. I then tried forcing maven to always use the snapshot repository but the snapshot repository rejected it because it didn't look like a snapshot. :(

Comment: Why do you care if it is a snapshot or release repo? I would always push it to the release and do docker testing on that release version if the tests fail you can always remove it from the release repo, or leave it to have some history of failed releases.

Comment: It's a fair point. I'm just trying to fit in with the maven / corporate way. However if I can't figure out a better solution I might try this.

Comment: I do this at my work - fits continuous delivery pretty nicely